# YUI AutoComplete: how do you get it to expand when the input is selected?

Tags: yui, yui-autocomplete

I've got a YUI AutoComplete control, works great.  Except that I'd like it to expand the list of suggestions as soon as the user selects the input box.  How do I make that happen?

Right now expansion doesn't happen until the user hits a key in the box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [textboxFocusEvent](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/docs/YAHOO.widget.AutoComplete.html#event_textboxFocusEvent) to send a query of the contents of the input, which will open the results pane. I tried using [expandContainer](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/docs/YAHOO.widget.AutoComplete.html#method_expandContainer) without success but wasn't sure that would have worked anyways.

Working Example: http://tivac.com/yui2/autocomplete_jamesmoore.htm

Answer (score 1):

Tivac has the right idea -- use textboxFocusEvent to send an empty query that returns results to populate the container. Check out this example for some sample code: http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/autocomplete/ac_combobox.html

Comment: Yes, although you probably don't want to just send an empty query.  The user could be coming back to a field that has something in it, so query with the contents (which will be empty to start with).

Answer (score 1):

This works when using *YUI 3*:

```
Y.one('#id').plug(Y.Plugin.AutoComplete, {source:['item1','item2','item3','etc']})
            .on('focus', function(){this.ac.fire('query')});
```

On focus of the attached input (id), the `query` event is fired to populate the 'menu' and display it.